# Module initialization error on appengine dev server in python runtime

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-modules

I am creating a new python appengine application with 2 modules (2 yamls). The default yaml is app.yaml with sits in my project root directory. The second yaml file module1.yaml which sits in the module1 directory. I have the following configuration in module1.yaml

```
application: appID
module: module1
version: default
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: 500ms
  max_pending_latency: 1000ms
  max_concurrent_requests: 50

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: module1.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: MySQLdb
  version: latest
- name: ssl
  version: latest

inbound_services:
- warmup
- xmpp_message
- xmpp_presence
- xmpp_subscribe
- xmpp_error
```

In the same module1 directory, I have the file module1.app which has the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import webapp2

# Module Imports
import routes

# Define app
module1_app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(debug = True)

# Add to path
if 'libs' not in sys.path:
    sys.path[0:0] = ['libs']

# Add defined routes
routes.add_routes(module1_app)
```

In the same module1 directory I have routes.py which contains by routing configuration.

When I start the dev server using the following command

`python dev_appserver.py app.yaml module1/module1.yaml`, I receive the following output:

```
INFO     2015-03-18 15:56:05,149 api_server.py:172] Starting API server at: http://localhost:38640
INFO     2015-03-18 15:56:05,159 dispatcher.py:185] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-03-18 15:56:05,164 dispatcher.py:185] Starting module "module1" running at: http://localhost:8081
INFO     2015-03-18 15:56:05,167 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2015-03-18 15:56:06,493 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/servers/gae/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/user1/servers/gae/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/user1/servers/gae/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
ImportError: No module named module1
INFO     2015-03-18 15:56:06,510 module.py:709] comm: "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Can anyone explain this error to me ? What can I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directory `module1` is not in `sys.path` -- add into it an empty `__init__.py` to make it a package, and change

```
script: module1.app
```

to:

```
script: module1.module1.module1_app
```

Note I've also changed the name of the WSGI app object to reflect the actual name you've chosen to use given the assignment

```
module1_app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(debug = True)
```

That makes far too many reps of "module1", but, hey, those *are* the names you've chosen to use!-)